# Why is this code not launching Android widget

Tags: java, android

This is code I'm using to launch an app :

```
launchApp(context , packagemanager , "com.android.phone")

/*
     * Launch an application
     * 
     * @param c Context of application
     * 
     * @param pm the related package manager of the context
     * 
     * @param pkgName Name of the package to run
     */
    public static boolean launchApp(Context c, PackageManager pm, String pkgName) {
        // query the intent for lauching
        Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkgName);
        // if intent is available
        if (intent != null) {
            try {
                c.startActivity(intent);

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                // quick message notification
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(c, "Application Not Found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                // display message
                toast.show();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // by default, fail to launch
        return false;
    }
```

This code launches applications without error but not widgets. When attempt to launch a widget no exception is thrown and widget is not launched. Can the code be modified to launch a widget ?

Comment: can you post stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the concept of "application" in Android is slightly an extended one.

An application - technically a process - can have multiple activities, services, content providers and/or broadcast listeners. If at least one of them is running, the application is up and running (the process).

So, what you have to identify is how do you want to "start the application".

Ok... here's what you can try out:

Create an intent with `action=MAIN` and `category=LAUNCHER`. Get the `PackageManager` from the current context using `context.getPackageManager`:

```
packageManager.queryIntentActivity(<intent>, 0)
```

where `intent` has `category=LAUNCHER`, `action=MAIN` or

```
packageManager.resolveActivity(<intent>, 0)
```

to get the first activity with main/launcher. Get the `ActivityInfo` you're interested in. From the `ActivityInfo`, get the `packageName` and name. Finally, create another intent with with `category=LAUNCHER`, `action=MAIN`,

```
componentName = new ComponentName(packageName, name)
```

and

```
setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

Finally

```
context.startActivity(newIntent)
```